# Causal Impact Analysis in Python (A/B Testing)

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am doing a causal impact analysis in Python. This kind of analysis helps in measuring the impact in the Treatment group post intervention when compared to a control group (A/B Testing). I read some literature from here: https://www.analytics-link.com/post/2017/11/03/causal-impact-analysis-in-r-and-now-python

Let's say my data is in following format:

[image]

The following code works perfectly:

```
from causalimpact import CausalImpact
cut_off_point = 12
pre_period = [0,cut_off_point-1]
post_period = [cut_off_point,data.shape[0]-1]
impact = CausalImpact(data, pre_period, post_period)
impact.run()
impact.plot()
```

However, if I add an additional column of Date and try to split the treatment and control groups based on date, I get an error

Say, I define the pre period and post periods by date now like this:

```
pre_period = ['2020-04-27','2020-06-29']
post_period = ['2020-07-06','2020-07-27']
impact = CausalImpact(data, pre_period, post_period)
impact.run()
impact.plot()
```

I get an error:

```
ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: '2020-06-29'
```

I have converted the date to index but still getting the error.

Can anyone please help. There seems to be limited literature online on this library and its usage in A/B Testing. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before passing periods to `CausalImpact` define periods:

```
pre_period = [pd.to_datetime(date) for date in  ['2020-04-27','2020-06-29']]
post_period = [pd.to_datetime(date) for date in ['2020-07-06','2020-07-27']]
```

Now periods are time-series objects, for example `pre_period`:

```
[Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-03-12 00:00:00')]
```

is a list of `Timestamp`.
After that try:

```
impact = CausalImpact(data, pre_period, post_period)
impact.run()
impact.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is a dataframe, but you are providing dates in the `pre_period` and `post_period` objects, which require your data be be a time series object instead. This is explained in the original R package documentation [here](http://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html).

To sum up: provide indices for dataframes, provide dates for time series.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me, it raises TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date' in a pretty equal dataset (one date column and control/test group columns) Doesnt seem a very general solution

Answer (score 0):

For those finding this question there's also the possibility of using the new [tfcausalimpact](https://github.com/WillianFuks/tfcausalimpact) library for running causal impact in Python (it was built on top of TensorFlow).

Here's an [example](https://github.com/WillianFuks/tfcausalimpact/blob/master/notebooks/getting_started.ipynb) to solve this problem on the new package:

```
dated_data = data.set_index(pd.date_range(start='20200101', periods=len(data)))

pre_period = ['20200101', '20200311']
post_period = ['20200312', '20200409']

ci = CausalImpact(dated_data, pre_period, post_period)
```

Notice that the package allows specifying the interval periods as `strings` as long as the index of the input data is of type `pandas.index.datetime`.